# Can China still be punished under UNCLOS in the Philippines v China case?

Tags: international-relations, international-law, china, international-courts, philippines

I have been learning about conflicts in the South China Sea involving China. I remember when the [Philippines led an arbitration case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philippines_v._China) against China and I still don't understand why an international court couldn't complete the case.

Is it possible that this case could still result in some kind of punishment for China under the [United Nations Convention on the Law of the Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Convention_on_the_Law_of_the_Sea) (UNCLOS)?

Comment: Which court are you thinking about? The International Court of Justice? The arbitral tribunal did apparently complete its work but it's in the nature of arbitration that it requires at least some level of consent from both parties to be effective. Arguably, even international courts require that. Also, the goal here (and in many ICJ border dispute cases) is not punishment for any past perceived wrongdoing but to help the parties resolve competing claims and converge on a common definition of borders and exclusive economic zones.

Comment: It was the International Court of Justice in The Hague, Netherlands. Related to Relaxed